# Drag and Drop sort to INSERT in MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, sorting

I'm displaying  a sortable list from my database using this PHP MySQL.

```
<?php                           
     $query  = "SELECT * FROM question_four ORDER BY recordListingID ASC";
     $result = mysql_query( $query );           
     while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result, MYSQL_ASSOC ) ) {
?>
        <li id="recordsArray_<?php echo $row['recordID']; ?>"><?php echo $row['recordText']; ?></li>
<?php 
     } 
?>
```

Instead of Updating the same table I tried to insert it into a new table using this code:

```
$action = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['action']);
$updateRecordsArray = $_POST['recordsArray'];
if ( $action == "updateRecordsListings" ) {
    $listingCounter = 1;
    foreach ( $updateRecordsArray as $recordIDValue ) {
        $query1 = "INSERT into answers_questionfour(id,recordListingID,recordID,recordText) values ('.$user_fbid.','.$listingCounter.', '.$recordIDValue.','.$recordText.')";
        mysql_query( $query1 ) or die('Error, insert query failed');
        $listingCounter = $listingCounter + 1;
    }
}
```

But, right now, it is inserting for one user only. When other users are trying to submit their sorted list. It doesn't add in the table. Can you help me figure it out? Thanks

Comment: Stop using mysql_*, use prepae statement PDO or mysqli_*

Comment: Yes I'm using PDO with my other scripts. I just borrowed that script for my drag and drop.Unfortunately, I'm having issues.

Answer (score 0):

Dinesh is certainly right about the security issues. But in any case, you need to surround your data values (especially the string types!) with quotes (`'`) but *leave out* the concatenation operators (`.`) since the whole sql string is already enclosed by `"`:

```
 $sql="INSERT into answers_questionfour(id,recordListingID,recordID,recordText) 
   values ('$user_fbid','$listingCounter', '$recordIDValue','$recordText')"
```

In PDO syntax this would be

```
$sql="INSERT into answers_questionfour(id,recordListingID,recordID,recordText) 
   values (?,?,?,?)";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array($user_fbid,$listingCounter, $recordIDValue,$recordText));
```

with `$dbh` being the database handler assigned to the PDO object.

Comment: Yes sir, but my Insert Query doesn't add the sorted list from other users. It only accepts mine. (it accepts the first INSERTED rows and nothing else. )

Comment: What are the values for `$user_fbid`, are they numeric or string? ... And what are the constraints on table `answers_questionfour`? Can you echo a few of the failed `insert` commands?